# Unable to get flash working with Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-extensions, chromium

I have Chromium Version 43.0.2335.0 (64-bit) on Windows 7. I am unable to get Flash working with it. The docs for Chrome (not Chromium) say that I should go to Plugins options and enable Flash. But in plugins, I don't see Flash as an installed plugin. So I installed flash but I still see the get Adobe Flash Player message when I visit any flash enabled page.

I have had flash working on Chromium on an older machine with a older version of Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried installing/uninstalling/booting nothing worked. Finally, this is what worked.

I installed Flash, not the default flash from Adobe site which Chrome tells you to do, but from here - https://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/flashplayer/latest/help/install_flash_player_ppapi.exe

I got this download link here - http://chromium.woolyss.com/#flash

PPAPI is what is required for Chromimum.